# Datepicker for 12 months of a particular year

Tags: jquery, date

I want to display calendar of the 12 months of a particular year(selected by user) in jquery, i have used the jquery ui datepicker for that

the code is as below

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display multiple months</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 12,
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="datepicker" ></div>


</body>
</html>
```

but it is not fullfilling my purpose , because it is showing 12 months from the present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you read the **[documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)**?

`numberOfMonths` is just *how* it will show the months, not which ones.

I think this is what you want:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 12,
    minDate: new Date(2013, 1 -1, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2013, 12 -1, 31),
    showButtonPanel: true
});
```

the `-1` in months is because JS months are zero-based.

You can use `Date` object to get current year's number.

Comment: yeahhh , that has worked but what is the method to show the calendar in grid view i.e. 6 months in above part of page and 6 in lower part ???

Comment: You can use array to specify the grid size, like this: `numberOfMonths: [4, 3]` - 4 rows with 3 months in each